# How to DNS ip change to 1.1.1.1 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dns

I want to browse the web by changing the gateway of the app to 1.1.1.1. But I can't change the DNS address of the Client to 1.1.1.1, Please help me.

I am making a webview app. I tried to make the configuration to be able to change the DNS, but the problem was searched a lot but could not be found.

Comment: Just get the Cloudflare App.  Free, simple to install.

Comment: I did some quick research and found the following:

There are open issues for the `http` package:

 - https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36551
 - https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/222
  
It seems to be unsupported at the moment.